# I am trying to calculate Ratios for Gender Neutral Names Using Gender

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add another column for gender_ratios.
If the gender field is 'F', the ratio is the women's total over the total for the name. Otherwise, it is calculated as the men's total over the total for the name. Line #3

```
spark.sql(""" SELECT name, women, men, (men + women) AS total,
IF(men > women, 'M', "F") as gender
IF(gender = F), SUM(women)/SUM(name), SUM(men)/SUM(name) AS gender_ratios
FROM customer
""")
```

[Without gender_ratio column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw7qT.png)

Comment: Do you have sample data(reproducible code ) set for it

Comment: Hello, I've attached an image without unable to add gender_ratio column. The error message I get "ParseException: 
mismatched input 'IF' expecting {, ';'}(line 3, pos 0)"